# Choosing which Java executable to run on Windows

Tags: java, windows

I got applications that need different versions of Java to run properly. I noticed that `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` gets highest precedence in the `PATH` variable. This folder contains `java.exe`, `javaw.exe`, and `javaws.exe`. These appear to be symbolic links that point to, in my case, executable targets in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin`.

Without using mklink to modify the targets to use another JRE, is there a better way to change the JRE to use?

Comment: Assuming that you have a number of programs that need to run simultaneously (or at least on the same machine), I'd recommend embedding the JRE you want within your application (ie copy the JRE you need to a relative location of the application and use a exe wrapper, batch file or short cut to use it)

Comment: Actually what I need is eclipse.exe to sometimes run JRE 1.6 and sometimes JRE 1.7 or even 1.8. When I run eclipse.exe, it just runs the java.exe that appears first in the PATH variable.

Comment: Could you clarify why you need Eclipse to run different versions of the JRE?  Typically what you do is install inside Eclipse different versions of the JDK and then select each project to run against either one of those.

Comment: It's complicated. I also use IBM Websphere Message Broker, which HAS to run JRE 1.6 to support our business applications that run on it. Sometimes I just prefer to use Eclipse instead when developing Java for it, which necessitates 1.6. However, for other applications not built from message broker, I can use later versions of Eclipse.

Comment: Wes, the version of Java that Eclipse is running under is NOT the same thing as the version of Java that Eclipse is compiling to and/or running your applications under. @Bane alluded to this. There are several places in Eclipse where you specify the version of Java that a particular project should use. The different places relate to the way you have your projects configured. For instance, if you are using Plug-in Projects, you would go into preferences, then PDE preferences, then specify a target platform including a preferred version of the JRE/JDK.

Comment: @Wes for clarity, I manage hundreds of small web apps, running on a dozen different environments, requiring anywhere from JDK 1.5-1.7.  I don't launch eclipse, however, with anything other than 1.7.  Instead, each project gets configured to reflect which version IT needs to be compiled against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need that eclipse run itself under a specific jvm, check this link: [Eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) ... Then,

add the -vm option at eclipse.ini file; e.g. `-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe`

Answer (score 1):

You can select the JVM version by passing on the command line the argument **-version:release**

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABDJJFI

Answer (score 0):

if those apps need different versions of java, you can launch them using a batch file and invoking say

```
c:\somepath\java.exe -jar pathToSomeJAR
```

or if they have the classes flat out in a folder you can do

```
c:\somepath\java.exe someClassWithStaticMainMethod.class
```